# Make JPG image stick to bottom of webpage without stretching

Tags: html, css, image

Hey guys I'm trying to get an image to stick to the bottom of my website. I can get it to stick to the bottom but then it stretches... This is my code:

```
<style>
    img {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
    }
</style>
<img src="fire.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Instead of nicely sticking to the bottom of my webpage and changing dimensions as the webpage changes it's size, it just stretches around. All other Stack Overflow tips just do the same. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why would you write `width="100%" height="100%"` if you don't want it to stretch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after is this:

```
<style>
.background-img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(/images/fire.jpg);
    background-size: cover; /* or "contain" */
    background-position: center bottom;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="background-img"></div>
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

It's difficult to make an image do what you're asking for without distortion or unwanted vertical height issues.

Comment: I have been using z-index's till now to make this image in the background. Am I able to commit this since it is now a background image?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You shouldn't have to manipulate z-index if you arrange the HTML as I have, with the content element falling after the background.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```css
div {
background: #F3F3F4 url("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CC6No3LtfEY/T6PQLbfzNBI/AAAAAAAAMhI/E7mlV7hya4M/s1600/google.jpg") no-repeat bottom;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: fixed;
   
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you skip width and height the image will use its default size and stick to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the `width` and `height` properties of your `img` tag. Then add to your img css `max-width: 100%` that will make your image responsive, and adapt to the screen size.